# Tag Name from EC2-group in Ansible

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

This is another question coming from the following post...:

[loops over the registered variable to inspect the results in ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321193/loops-over-the-registered-variable-to-inspect-the-results-in-ansible/30585964#30585964)

So basically having:

```
    - name: EC2Group | Creating an EC2 Security Group inside the Mentioned VPC
       local_action:
         module: ec2_group
         name: "{{ item.sg_name }}"
         description: "{{ item.sg_description }}"
         region: "{{ vpc_region }}" # Change the AWS region here
         vpc_id: "{{ vpc.vpc_id }}" # vpc is the resgister name, you can also set it manually
         state: present
         rules: "{{ item.sg_rules }}"
       with_items: ec2_security_groups
       register: aws_sg
- name: Tag the security group with a name
  local_action:
   module: ec2_tag
   resource: "{{ item.group_id }}"
   region: "{{ vpc_region }}"
   state: present
   tags:
     Name: "{{vpc_name }}-group"
  with_items: aws_sg.results
```

I wonder how is possible to get the TAG NAME

```
 tags:
     Name: "{{ item.sg_name }}"
```

The same value as per the primary name definition on the Security Groups?

```
   local_action:
     module: ec2_group
     name: "{{ item.sg_name }}"
```

I am trying to make that possible but I am not sure how to do it. If it's also possible to retrieve that item?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Tags are available after the ec2.py inventory script is run - they always take the value of `tag_key_value` where 'key' is the name of the tag, and 'value' is the value within that tag. i.e. if you create a tag called 'Application' and give it a value of 'AwesomeApplication' you would get 'tag_Application_AwesomeApplication'.

That said, if you have just created instances and want to run some commands against those new instances, parse the output from the create instance command to get a list of the IP addresses, and add them to a temporary group, and then you can run commands against that group within the same playbook:

```
...
    - name: add hosts to temporary group
      add_host: name="{{ item }}" groups=temporarygroup
      with_items: parsedipaddresses
- hosts: temporarygroup
  tasks:
    - name: awesome script to do stuff goes here
...
```

Comment: Hi.. My question is related to ec2_group.py as I am creating groups and those tags should be only for the groups.
The issue I am having is just the TAG name as I do not know how to extract it from the   module: ec2_group so to import that value into the tag name from the ec2_tag module